# Codename one:Unable to set Toastbar position at centre

Tags: codenameone, mobile-application

I am not able to set Toastbar at centre position. I am using below code to set toastbar at centre position "ToastBar.getInstance().setPosition(Component.CENTER);"
But this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center would probably take up the entire screen. Currently the only two supported values for position are `TOP` & `BOTTOM` as indicated in the param argument in the javadoc.

Comment: Is there any other option to show toast bar at centre of the screen?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would expect it to appear. These are meant to be non-intrusive. Why not use a `Dialog` or `InteractionDialog`?